# Incidence matrix of a graph as a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

My question is about a linear system $A x = b$ in which the matrix $A$ is the $|E| \times |V|$ incidence matrix of a graph $G = (V,E)$, where $|E| > |V|$. I would like to know: under what conditions is the system of equations consistent, and what does this say about the graph? In particular, if we view the vector $b$ as a set of edge weights on the graph, what does a solution of this system of equations tell us about those weights $b$?

I know that Kirchhoff's current law (viewing the graph as an electrical network) can be formulated in this way, and that *I think* Kirchhoff's voltage law is a statement about whether or not the system of equations is consistent.

But does this mean that if the system of equations is consistent, then the sum of the weights around any cycle in the graph is zero?